# PL/PgSQL: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to write a `dateadd()` function using PL/PgSQL. I want to be able to add anything from seconds, right up to years to a date/timestamp. have cobbled together a function (from snippets etc obtained online), and have come up with this "implementation":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dateadd(diffType VARCHAR(15), incrementValue int, inputDate timestamp) RETURNS timestamp AS $$
DECLARE
   YEAR_CONST Char(15) := 'year';
   MONTH_CONST Char(15) := 'month';
   DAY_CONST Char(15) := 'day';
   HOUR_CONST Char(15) := 'hour';
   MIN_CONST Char(15) := 'min';
   SEC_CONST Char(15) := 'sec';

   dateTemp Date;
   intervals interval;
BEGIN
   IF lower($1) = lower(YEAR_CONST) THEN
       select cast(cast(incrementvalue as character varying) || ' year' as interval) into intervals;
   ELSEIF lower($1) = lower(MONTH_CONST) THEN
       select cast(cast(incrementvalue as character varying) || ' months' as interval) into intervals;
   ELSEIF lower($1) = lower(DAY_CONST) THEN
       select cast(cast(incrementvalue as character varying) || ' day' as interval) into intervals;
   ELSEIF lower($1) = lower(HOUR_CONST) THEN
       select cast(cast(incrementvalue as character varying) || ' hour' as interval) into intervals;
   ELSEIF lower($1) = lower(MIN_CONST) THEN
       select cast(cast(incrementvalue as character varying) || ' minute' as interval) into intervals;
   ELSEIF lower($1) = lower(SEC_CONST) THEN
       select cast(cast(incrementvalue as character varying) || ' second' as interval) into intervals;
   END IF;

   dateTemp:= inputdate + intervals;

   RETURN dateTemp;
END;
$$ IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, when I try to use the function, I get the following error:

```
template1=# select dateadd('hour', 1, getdate());
ERROR:  function dateadd(unknown, integer, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: select dateadd('hour', 1, getdate());
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
template1=#
```

Why is the function not being found by PG?

I am running PG 9.3 on Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS

Comment: Incidentally, a lot of your questions here seem to be making "emulations" of functions from MS SQL Server. Given that the two will never quite behave the same, I can't help thinking your energy would be better spent learning the equivalent PostgreSQL functionality instead.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli It might be better to use something like `intervals := interval '1 year' * incrementvalue;`. It is easier to understand.

Comment: Is your intention to write a drop-in replacement of the related MS function or just to get an efficient function?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I just want a drop-in replacement for now. Will worry about optimisation once I have everything working.

Comment: Note that this will never actually work as a drop-in replacement (in the sense of queries working the same under both DBMS's), since the MS SQL function takes bare words as the datepart argument, whereas here they will need to be quoted strings. Since you're changing the calling code anyway, you could just change it to e.g. `some_date + interval '2 months'` (or `some_date + '2 months'::interval`; somehow I prefer that syntax although it's more idiosyncratic to Postgres).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll kick yourself: the difference between the line that's erroring (and the next few) and the one before it is that you've accidentally added an underscore in the wrong place:

You have

```
HOUR_CONST_Char(15) := 'hour';
```

It should be

```
HOUR_CONST Char(15) := 'hour';
```

***EDIT***

The updated question is suffering from Postgres's slightly fussy type system: your `getdate()` function is returning `timestamp with time zone`, but your `dateadd` accepts a `timestamp` (i.e. `timestamp without time zone`). Using the Postgres short-hand for cast of `value::type`, this should work ([SQLFiddle demo, using `now()` in place of `getdate()`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/201a8/4))

```
select dateadd('hour', 1, getdate()::timestamp);
```

However, you have a few other odd type selections:

- Your "constants" are `Char(15)`, but aren't 15 characters long, so will be padded with spaces; you should probably use `VarChar(15)`, or even just `text` (unlike MS SQL, in Postgres, all strings are stored out-of-page dynamically, and a `VarChar` is essentially just `text` with a maximum length constraint).
- Your intermediate variable (which can probably be refactored out) is of type `Date`, not `Timestamp`, so will truncate the input to just the date part, no time.

Finally, I'll note one fundamental optimisation: you don't need to `lower()` your constants, because you already know they're lower case. :)

Comment: Grrr! it must be time for another cup of cofee ;)!. Apart from that typo though, is the rest of the logic ok? i.e. will it do what I want to do? (i.e. add anything from secs to years to a datetie or date?) - I am quite new to PL/PgSQL. Thanks

Comment: Fixed, but function still not working .. please see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

It's the underscore between HOUR_CONST and Char(15) You should enter "HOUR_CONST Char(15)" instead of "HOUR_CONST_Char(15)"