# st_makepoint does not exist spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spatial

I am trying to query spatial data using the below native query. and I am getting below exception in doing so.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT \* FROM locations WHERE ST_Contains(polygon, ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:x, :y), 4326), 3785))")
List\<Location\> test(@Param("x") double x,@Param("y") double y);
```

Exception I am getting

> ERROR: function st_makepoint(double precision, double precision) does not exist
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

tried adding the below configs

> hibernate-spatial dependency
>
> properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG95Dialect");`

Note:
If I execute same query directly on db , its working

Comment: Dependency used -> 
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
   <version>5.6.2.Final</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details.  I tried formatting it but I am not sure if the slashes you added were to escape the site or are part of your query.  Please edit to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I uses myBatis and the native query as following

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE public.ST_DWithin(last_location::public.geography, public.ST_SetSRID(public.ST_MakePoint(#{longitude}::float, #{latitude}::float), 4326)::public.geography, #{rangeInMeter}) LIMIT #{limit}")
List\<Object\> findVehiclesInRangeFromLatLon(@Param("longitude") double longitude, @Param("latitude") double latitude, @Param("rangeInMeter") int rangeInMeter, @Param("limit") int limit);
```

In mybatis, using `#{param}` to pass the parameter to the query.

You can check on this answer for more https://stackoverflow.com/a/56888200/1721946